# Visualise Option is not active on Azure machine learning service

Tags: azure, csv, azure-machine-learning-service

hi I am new to Azure Machine learning Service. I uploaded imported CSV files in Data set and when i drag and drop them in Blank experiment, I am unable to visualize it or it fails to detect any columns. Is there any suggestions on how to rectify this problem

Answer (score 1):

there is a known issue of visual interface in azure machine learning service. The tutorial shows a workaround: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/ui-tutorial-automobile-price-train-score

Basically since the azure machine learning service doesn't have default compute at this moment, the user needs to manually run a graph first to generate the data profile to visualize the data.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your input.